# Creating a new .txt file with date in front, C#

Tags: c#, datetime, text-files

I am trying to get the following:  [today's date]___[textfilename].txt from the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication29
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            WriteToFile();

        }

        static void WriteToFile()
        {

            StreamWriter sw;
            sw = File.CreateText("c:\\testtext.txt");
            sw.WriteLine("this is just a test");
            sw.Close();
            Console.WriteLine("File created successfully");



        }
    }
}
```

I tried putting in `DateTime.Now.ToString()` but i cannot combine the strings.

Can anybody help me?  I want the date in FRONT of the title of the new text file I am creating.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
static void WriteToFile(string directory, string name)
{
    string filename = String.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd}__{1}", DateTime.Now, name);
    string path = Path.Combine(directory, filename);
    using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(path))
    {
        sw.WriteLine("This is just a test");
    }
}
```

To call:

```
WriteToFile(@"C:\mydirectory", "myfilename");
```

Note a few things:

- Specify the date with a custom format string, and avoid using characters illegal in NTFS.
- Prefix strings containing paths with the '@' string literal marker, so you don''t have to escape the backslashes in the path.
- Combine path parts with Path.Combine(), and avoid mucking around with path separators.
- Use a using block when creating the StreamWriter; exiting the block will dispose the 
  StreamWriter, and close the file for you automatically.

Comment: Wish I could more than +1 on this. Your excellent notes give the answers behind the answer.

Comment: No need for a StreamWriter: File.WriteAllText(path, "This is just a test");

Comment: @John: I was trying to strike a balance between retaining the OP's original content and structure, and suggesting best practices.  But yes, absolutely, if you're writing just one line.

Comment: Just personal taste, but I'd have put the formatting string inside the original string: string.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd}__{1}", DateTime.Now, name);

Answer (score 13):

You'd want to do a custom string format on DateTime.Now.  You can use String.Format() to combine the results of that with your base filename.

To append on the path to the filename, use Path.Combine().

Finally, use a using() block to properly close & dispose your StreamWriter when you are finished with it...

```
string myFileName = String.Format("{0}__{1}", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddhhnnss"), "MyFileName");
strign myFullPath = Path.Combine("C:\\Documents and Settings\\bob.jones\\Desktop", myFileName)
using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(myFullPath))
{
    sw.WriteLine("this is just a test");
}

Console.WriteLine("File created successfully");
```

Edit: fixed sample to account for path of "C:\Documents and Settings\bob.jones\Desktop"

Comment: string myFileName = String.Format("{0}__{1}", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddhhnnss"), "MyFileName");
            StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(myFileName);

Comment: this works for the most part...but how can i specify the exact path in where this .txt should be created in?  for example, i want this .txt file to be created on C:\\Documents and Settings\\bob.jones\\Desktop  how would i specify this?

Comment: +1 for stripping out non-digit, possibly illegal in file names characters via formatting.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
string fileTitle = "testtext.txt";
string fileDirectory = "C:\\Documents and Settings\username\My Documents\";
File.CreateText(fileDirectory + DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMYYYY") + fileTitle);
```

?

Comment: Keep in mind that a DateTime can contain Characters illegal in a Path, for example the forward slash / that some cultures use as a separator.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question in your comment on [@Scott Ivey's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/941132/creating-a-new-txt-file-with-date-in-front-c/941151#941151):
to specify where the file is written to, prepend the desired path to the file name before or in the call to CreateText().

For example:

```
String path = new String (@"C:\Documents and Settings\bob.jones\Desktop\");
StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(path + myFileName);
```

or

```
String fullFilePath = new String (@"C:\Documents and Settings\bob.jones\Desktop\");
fullFilePath += myFileName;
StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(fullFilePath);
```